# Excel 2013 FILTERXML() returns wrong value?

Tags: xml, excel, xpath, excel-2013

When I use Excel 2013's new `webservice()` and `filterxml()`, it seems that I'm getting different results from if I just open the xml in a web browser.  specifically, I'm trying to use excel to access an API from the department of energy.  The address with pubilc access key is:

http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=449E5B5A53EBB9601A80681EBFFBB91E&series_id=PET.MTTUA_NUS_1.M&num=150&out=xml

When I use a web browser to access the address above, the Dec-13 value is shown as 9931:

```
...
<row>
  <date>201312</date>
  <value>9931</value>
...
```

I know this to be the correct value.

However, when I try to access this through the new excel formula, I get a weird result... most months are correct, but some are wrong... Dec-13, for instance, returns a value of 2,933,263.  No idea why - I cant see where this number is coming from.

I have used `WEBSERVICE()` with the address above, and then tried to use `FILTERXML()` to generate two side-by-side arrays, one of dates and the other of values:

For the dates, where K1 is the location of the `WEBSERVICE()` , with formula confirmed as an array :

```
=FILTERXML(K$1,"//date")
```

And to return values:

```
=FILTERXML(K$1,"/eia_api/series/row/data/row/value")
```

I tried lots of other combinations, too, but i'm super new to XPATH and have obviously missed something.

Could someone help me with  `FILTERXML()` function that perfectly replicates in Excel the (correct!) data that I can see when I access the XML via a web browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have excell 2013, but am fammiliar with xpath.

Have you considered just one xpath, to return value pairs, rather than two?

for example: `//data/row` or  `//data/row//text()`

or (provided excell uses Xpath 2.0) something like: `//data/row//string-join(text(),';')`

DO REMEMBER to confirm the formula using `Ctrl-shift-enter` so that the results array expand to correct size.

Comment: Thanks!  I wouldnt mind having value pairs returned, but the two suggestions you gave only retun #VALUE!.  I wonder if I'm not treating it properly as an array or something?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the Xpath 2.0 suggestion above as well - also still returning #VALUE!.  And yes, I've confirmed as an array but still no luck.  Forgetting about excel for a moment, what Xpath would you use to return a vector of all "values," given this xml?  is there something about my approach (in original post) that is incorrectly specified or somehow causes it to return things other than "value" ?  Thanks.

Comment: I would simply use: `//data/row/value` and `//data/row/date` or with optional text(): `//data/row/value/text()` and `//data/row/date/text()`

Comment: Have you considered using IMPORTXML() in GoogleSheets instead? I find it quite reliable, and all of the network load goes through google servers instead of you own connection...